# MYSQL fix numbering in group concat

Tags: mysql

How can I fix this query on numbering the group concat? It seems that every rows it continuing the numbering. I didnt set variable (SET:@a=0;) for it didnt work in PHP somehow. Below is the query :

```
CREATE TABLE `abms` (
  `id` bigint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tick_id` bigint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_desc` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=187 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into abms values 
(182, 1, 'ABC'), 
(183, 1, 'DEF'), 
(184, 1, 'GHI'), 
(185, 2, 'ABC'), 
(186, 2, 'GHI');

Select
tick_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(@a:=@a+1,') ',text_desc SEPARATOR '\n') as text_desc
From
abms
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 0) AS dummy
GROUP BY tick_id
```

Result:

```
===================
tick_id || text_desc
1          1) ABC 2) DEF 3) GHI
2          4) ABC 5) GHI
===================
```

Expected Result :

```
===================
tick_id || text_desc
1          1) ABC 2) DEF 3) GHI
2          1) ABC 2) GHI
===================
```

Comment: Does this work: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56609. TBH it's the same row if you don't use `GROUP BY`, so it will not work. See the code I made: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38a9689/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a further variable to keep track of the previous `tick_id`, you can then use this to reset `@a` to 1 each time the tick changes:

```
SELECT t.tick_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.RowNum,') ',text_desc ORDER BY RowNum SEPARATOR '\n') as text_desc
FROM    (  SELECT   tick_id,
                    text_desc,
                    CASE WHEN IF(tick_id <> @t, @a := 1,@a := @a+1) IS NULL THEN NULL
                        WHEN (@t := tick_id) IS NULL THEN NULL
                        ELSE @a
                    END AS RowNum
            FROM abms
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 0, @t := 0) AS dummy
            ORDER BY tick_id, text_desc
        ) AS t
GROUP BY t.tick_id;
```

**[Example on db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a6dd799fa93eb3af758beea8caed297b)**

I've added a subquery and done the numbering outside of the group concatenation, because when using variables in this manner you need to apply an order by to ensure the rows are read correctly, and that order by won't work with the `GROUP BY` so it needs to be done in two steps.